# Mobile Internet in St Petersburg

Tags: russia, internet, mobile-operators

I am about to travel to St Petersburg for one day and I am concerned about mobile internet. I own both a German and a Romanian SIM card, but none of the providers seem to offer a plan for Russia (only EU, USA, Canada, Turkey, etc). Please correct me if I'm wrong, but there is no logical reason why the EU plans should include Russia.

Is my only option buying a prepaid SIM as soon as I get there? It seems quite odd that there are no plans available for Russia. How did other other people who traveled there solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "there are no plans"? Of course you can use your German sim-card in Russia. But it will cost you, well, depending on your carrier maybe 1€ or 2€ per megabyte or maybe even more.

Comment: If it's of any use to you almost every café, bar and restaurant will have WiFi for customers, WiFi is very common in big Russian cities.

Comment: Wifi in Russia requires the russian mobile phone, so the easiest and cheapest way is to get a sim card (not in airport, by the way)

Comment: I guess prepaid card it is, since it's required for WiFi. Thank you for that information.

Comment: @Neusser I meant there are no reasonably priced plans. I should have included that in my question.